# JS code not working for ajax loaded views

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following javascript code(it's not mine):

```
(function ($) {
    // Code goes here
    $.fn.switcher = function (opts) {
        var defaults = {
            btn: '.info_btn', // button class
            block: '.details_info', //block for hide
            hideifout: false, 
            classActive: 'open' 
            //classNotActive:'close'
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
        this.each(
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var btn = $this.find(options.btn);
                var block = $this.find(options.block);
                var plaing = false;
                var click = function (e) {
                    if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    if (plaing) return;
                    plaing = true;
                    if (block.is(':visible')) {
                        block.hide('blind', function () {
                            btn.removeClass(options.classActive);
                            btn.css('z-index', 0);
                            plaing = false;
                        });
                    } else {
                        btn.addClass(options.classActive);
                        btn.css('z-index', 2);
                        block.show('blind', function () {

                            plaing = false;
                        });
                    }
                }

                btn.click(click);
                if (options.hideifout) {
                    block.mouseleave(click);
                }

            }
        );
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This code  expand/shrink `div` block. This code locate in `main.js` file.  The `main.js` is included in master page. It works well for non-ajax request. For a ajax loaded partial view it not works. My solution is:

```
$('#somediv').load('some action', function () {

            $('.infoBlock').switcher();

            $('div.widgets').switcher(
                    {
                        btn: '.expand',
                        block: '.voice_block',
                        hideifout: true                        
                    });            
        });
```

I have to put this block of code anywere.
May be, there are the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're having to do this is because your original code is binding the events when the document loads. Therefore you have to make the same call after the Ajax request finishes loading and the new elements are added to the DOM.

The easiest way that I can see that will prevent you from having to do what you're currently doing is to rely on a standard set of Css class names that you can use (the default class names that are defined in *your* code would work), and have a generic callback method defined.

I don't have your HTML here so I'm flying blind. But on the elements:

```
<div class="expand">...</div> 
<div class="voice_block"> ... </div>
```

You would have:

```
<div class="expand info_btn">...</div> 
<div class="voice_block details_info"> ... </div>
```

and then you could have a function

```
function genericCallback(){
 $('body').switcher();
}
```

Which could be called on every request

```
$('#somediv').load('some action', genericCallback);
```

Obviously this can be tweaked for performance gains as this is just a proof of concept. For example, depending on the size of your DOM, performing an enumeration of all elements during the `switcher()` call may not be advisable.

Also, in this example I've kept your `expand` and `voice_block` classes from the original elements on my revised elements, I've only done this to prove that you can keep your original classes that might distinguish the elements (differing styles etc) while remaining unobtrusive.

Comment: Thanks. I caught your message. I will try.